# PHP Class field getting changed before getting returned

Tags: php, class

I am having an issue with a PHP class field which doesn't want to set using my setter method. While inside the setter method everything seems to be fine, as soon as the method finishes, it's like the data is gone.

This class has other setter and getter methods but they seem to be fine. Looking through the code and it all seems to be the same.

```
private $volunteerType // declare class field

// Function to call class field data
public function getVolunteerType()
{
    // Where my issue currently is... 
    // $this->volunteerType seems to be blank.
    // can't figure out why
    return $this->volunteerType;
}

// Method to set class field data
public function setVolunteerType($inVolunteerType)
{
        $this->volunteerType = $this->valVolunteerType($inVolunteerType);
        // If I do a 
        // die($this->volunteerType);
        // I get the expected result.
        // e.g. 1,2,3,4,5
}

// Method to validate data before it is set in the setter
// Takes in an array of integers
private function valVolunteerType($vol_type)
{
        $validVolunteerType = "";
    foreach($vol_type as $vType)
    {
        $validVolunteerType .= $vType.",";
    }
    $validVolunteerType = rtrim($validVolunteerType, ",");

    return $validVolunteerType;
}
```

Can anyone please identify what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The setter should be working correctly. Is there any code inside the class that modifies that variable? Could you please show the calling code were the error occurs?

Comment: Can you post the entire class? And how you're instantiating the object / calling the methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After tightly working through each section. there was a part of code which was putting a string from a mysql table into this class which should have been an array.

the solution was to put an additional check into the validator section of the class to check if it was getting an array. Finally, my validator looks like

```
    private function valVolunteerType($vol_type)
{
    if(!is_array($vol_type))
    {
        $vol_type = explode(",", $vol_type);
    }

    $validVolunteerType = "";
    foreach($vol_type as $vType)
    {
        $validVolunteerType .= $vType.",";
    }
    $validVolunteerType = rtrim($validVolunteerType, ",");

    return $validVolunteerType;
}
```